# Failed maven build with 'ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required'

Tags: java, maven, http, https

An error occurred while building the Java project using the maven

> [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.4.1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.4.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.4.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.pom. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required. -> [Help 1]

Answer (score -1):

Due to the fact that the maven repository does not allow to load artifacts over http
Build failed because can't load clean plugin
For us, the solution worked to add pluginRepository with httpS url to main pom file

```
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
```